# slow performance

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu Linux 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 the performance is acceptable on my hardware with the exception of Ubuntu software center which is very slow to populate  and all related functions such as installing software and updates are slow as well however my web browsing works fine and is quick.  Also I am trying to get a Seagate Central NAS server recognized and accessible.  Any ideas would be appreciated?  Thanks